# Nao repetir thead em cada pagina de impressao

Tags: css, table

Ola,
estou tendo um problema. Nao quero imprimir o cabeçalho da tabela (thead) em cada folha da impressao e atualmente toda vez que vou imprimir a tabela e ela nao cabe na folha o cabeçalho da tabela repete. Nao quero isso.
Alguem sabe como remover?

Comment: Posta o código.

Answer (score 1):

Existe essa opção:

```
thead {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```